# Kubernetes - connection refuse using nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am learning Kubernetes, and I did create a LAB on a Bare-Metal, So I'm a Kubernetes noob!

I did create my `deployment` and it is running and accessible using `NodePort`, But when I use `nginx-ingress`, The nginx container is running and it is responding inside its container using `curl localhost`, but when I try from the outer world, I see this message: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to app.example.com port 80: Connection refused`

These are my `app-service.yml` and `app-ingress.yml` which they are running.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 3010
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: my-app
```

```yaml
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  labels:
    app: my-app
  annotations:
    # use the shared ingress-nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-app-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Also my deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app
          image: my-app:1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3010
```

The command: `kubectl get all --namespace ingress-nginx` is showing:

```
NAME                                            READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-create-tc8t7        0/1     Completed   0          73m
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-patch-lnbcp         0/1     Completed   2          73m
pod/ingress-nginx-controller-7fd7d8df56-bjmrm   1/1     Running     0          74m

NAME                                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.110.64.201    <none>        80:30532/TCP,443:31993/TCP   74m
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.108.186.241   <none>        443/TCP                      74m

NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller   1/1     1            1           74m

NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/ingress-nginx-controller-7fd7d8df56   1         1         1       74m

NAME                                       COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-create   1/1           5s         74m
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-patch    1/1           19s        74m
```

and the command: `kubectl get ing` is showing:

```sh
NAME          CLASS    HOSTS                  ADDRESS         PORTS   AGE
my-ingress   <none>   app.example.com         X.X.X.X         80      11m
```

Comment: how did you deploy your cluster? looks like you have regular service and those are not accessible outside the cluster

Comment: @Rico Is not the ```nginx-ingress``` job to do that accessible ```ClusterIP``` for outer world (and apply LB & etc)?

Comment: nah.. the clusterIP is only accessible within the cluster

Comment: you have to use a NodePort service to access it from outside

Comment: @Rico i don't want use ```NodePort``` i need LB! because of that i'm using ```INGRESS```!

Comment: type loadbalancer only works with certain cloud providers or infra. if your setup is not supported then you have to go with your own load balancer/proxy and forward to a nodeport

Comment: @Rico I know that, because of that i'm using ```INGRESS```

Comment: same with the ingress... you need a service to expose your ingress. read about how ingresses work

Comment: INGRESS is ls Exposed on 30532 for http! I missed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClusterIP` is not accessible from outside kubernetes cluster. `ClusterIP` provides L4 layer loadbalancing.

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/) you few options for nginx ingress on bare metal

1. Use MetalLB as pure software loadbalancer implementation
2. Use `NodePort` service to expose nginx ingress controller. Note you are not using `NodePort` to expose the regular pod.You are getting benefit of L7 layer load balancing by nginx.
3. Run nginx with `hostNetwork:true`

If you choose option 3 which is easiest in my opinion you can access the kubernetes pod via ingress using `curl http://<NODEIP> -H "Host: app.example.com"`

Comment: It is exposed, I missed the port-number is 30532! with using option 3, just can have one POD (or it can dynamic port assign i don't know).

Comment: nginx ingress controller will listen on port 80 on the bare metal server's network directly.Other pods you run normally and can be on any port

Comment: So i need another Nginx on ```Node``` to proxy! Why it can't expose to 80? only more than 30000 ?!!?

Comment: What you mean another `nginx` ? There is only one nginx process running as pod but on host network not on pod network. In this case you don't need a service to expose nginx..thats the advantage

Comment: So why that Nginx doesn't respond on port 80 from outside? Ingress is on my valid IP (x.x.x.x) on port 80. But it is not works, i can access using 30532 from internet.

Comment: Nodeport does not support 80..it only supports high range ports

Comment: So why ingress shows working on my valid IP on port 80? :(

Comment: Not sure if I am understanding your issue or question...I thought you are getting connection refused

Comment: Yes Ingress shows running on my valid IP with a host path on port 80. But connections on port 80 is refusing.

Comment: That's expected using `NodePort`..using option 3 solves it

Comment: Oh you mean enable hostNetwork on nginx deployment, i did do that on my app deployment. I am stupid!